# Vim: How to change/select function name

Tags: vim

Given:

```
function(param);
```

With the cursor anywhere on function, I can use ciw on function to replace it, or viw to select the function name.

How do I do the same thing in the following cases:

```
object.function(param);
object.function<blah>(param);
```

Note that ciW or viW does not work.  Does this require redefining how vim respects its 'words'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on the right track, you need to adjust the way vim separates words.

For this add `.` as a word separator:

```
:set iskeyword+=\.
```